# How-To install freefilesync on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management

Why is there no Version of freefilesync for Ubuntu 18.04 or KDE 18.04 LTS?

When I make executing the lines above I have the following line in the

```
freefilesync-ubuntu-ffs-bionic.list
```

But running then `apt-get update` gives the following ERROR:

```
Fehl:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                   
  404  Not Found [IE: Das Depot »http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu bionic Release« enthält keine Release-Datei.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
P: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Comment: The ppa you're trying to install from wasn't updated since 12/2015

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here:

- Use [FreeFileSync 9.2 from getdeb.net](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/17.04/?q=freefilesync) (for obsolete Ubuntu 17.04) - add repository, install package then remove repository:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb apps"
  sudo wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install freefilesync
  sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb apps"
  ```
- Download FreeFileSync 10.3 archive from [official site](https://freefilesync.org/download.php), extract it, create necessary shortcuts (*.desktop*-files), add to `PATH` variable, and enjoy:

  ```
  # 1. Create ~/Software folder and download here
  mkdir ~/Software
  cd ~/Software
  xdg-open https://freefilesync.org/download/FreeFileSync_10.3_Linux_64-bit.tar.gz
  # save to ~/Software
  # if it don't work - click on "Download FreeFileSync 10.3 Linux 64-bit"
  #xdg-open https://freefilesync.org/download.php

  # extract the program
  tar -xf FreeFileSync_10.3_Linux_64-bit.tar.gz
  cd FreeFileSync
  # extract icons
  unzip Resources.zip FreeFileSync.png RealTimeSync.png
  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/
  mv {FreeFileSync,RealTimeSync}.png ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/

  # 2. Create shortcuts for current user
  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/

  cat > ~/.local/share/applications/freefilesync.desktop << EOF
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=FreeFileSync
  Comment=Keep files and folders synchronized
  Exec=FreeFileSync %f
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Icon=FreeFileSync
  MimeType=application/x-freefilesync-ffs;application/x-freefilesync-batch
  Categories=Utility;FileTools;GTK;
  StartupWMClass=FreeFileSync
  StartupNotify=true
  EOF

  cat > ~/.local/share/applications/realtimesync.desktop << EOF
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=RealtimeSync
  Comment=Start synchronization in real time
  Exec=RealTimeSync %f
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Icon=RealTimeSync
  Categories=Utility;FileTools;GTK;
  MimeType=application/x-freefilesync-real
  StartupNotify=true
  EOF

  # add it to PATH
  echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/FreeFileSync" >> ~/.bashrc
  echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/FreeFileSync" >> ~/.profile
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```

then logout, log-in again and you will be able to use both *FreeFileSync* and *RealTimeSync*.

Comment: sorry I'm not that savvy with Ubuntu, I'm afraid I made some mistakes. I followed your steps on option 2 (download FreeFileSync), then put in ~/FreeFileSync (I changed PATH accordingly), after finished install, I logged out and in again, made them executable, trusted them on the first run, then I got an error said "there was an apps error" and changed the name to FreeFileSync (capitalized), but in terminal it showed freefilesync.desktop in green. What I'm missing? TIA

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure. Try to follow the instruction again line-by-line. I upgraded instruction to get 10.3 version and tested it on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS MATE clean VM. It works as expected.

Comment: I just tried to create a shortcut using shortcut launcher (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), it worked. The only thing that I can think of is the Category, which I don't have in my launcher.

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

1. Download Linux version from: https://freefilesync.org/download.php `tar.gz` file
2. Extract from `tar.gz`in File Manager using right button, 'extract here'. Alternatively, locate `tar.gz` in terminal and extract with

   `tar xzvf FreeFile`<kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Then, in terminal go to extraction folder `cd folderName` and run the script `./FreeFileSync_XX.XX_Install.run` (wait)
4. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> `free` to open
5. Right-click in icon to add to favorites (menu)

#### OLD - not necessary

3. In terminal (go to), `cd Downloads`, and move extracted:

   `sudo mv FreeFileSync_10.24_Linux/FreeFileSync/ /opt/`
4. Symlink (unfortunately it does not work with FreeFileSync file), so the binary must be chosen manually. In this case 64 bits (other option: `FreeFileSync_i686`)

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/FreeFileSync/Bin/FreeFileSync_x86_64 /usr/bin/FreeFileSync
   ```
5. Create .desktop file

   ```
   cat >$HOME/.local/share/applications/freefilesync.desktop <<'EOL'
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Keep files and folders synchronized
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/opt/FreeFileSync/Resources/FreeFileSync.png
   Name=FreeFileSync
   Exec=FreeFileSync %F 
   EOL
   ```
6. Create modifier of favorite-apps (left menu in ubuntu) with name of created .desktop

   ```
   cat >addToMenu.sh <<'EOL'
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   STATE=`gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`
   STATE=$(sed 's/]/,'\ \'freefilesync.desktop\'']/g' <<< $STATE)
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "${STATE}"
   EOL
   ```
7. Modify favorite-apps

   ```
    sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
    bash addToMenu.sh
   ```

(tested in ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

The depot "http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu bionic Release" does not contain a release file.
There is no package for Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) in this PPA