# How Do I Link to /usr/lib or /opt From /usr/bin?

Tags: symbolic-link

This is Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop edition, running the default Gnome desktop.

I am trying to install FreeFileSync which is a downloadable .tar.gz file (from here: https://freefilesync.org/download.php). Once unpacked the tarball contains a directory, which in turn contains the binaries, sample .desktop files and another directory with resources like icons and sounds etc.

My initial approach was to copy the FreeFileSync directory to /usr/lib, and then link to it from /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync /usr/bin/freefilesync
```

... and then edit the .desktop file setting Exec=/usr/bin/freefilesync, and copy it to /usr/share/applications/FreeFileSync.desktop

The result is rather strange and I can't figure it out.

- If I run FreeFileSync from the applications menu it starts as expected
- If I open a terminal at /usr/bin and type "freefilesync" it starts as expected
- But if I run "freefilesync" in a terminal from anywhere other than /usr/bin I get this response: "Cannot determine real path for "freefilesync": No such file or directory [realpath]"

I have also tried putting the FreeFileSync directory in /opt but the same thing happens. I have other apps installed like Zoom and Citrix Receiver which both use symlinks to binary files from /usr/bin to /opt, which work perfectly, and the links look identical to the one I created above.

Any help with this is much appreciated as I'm scratching my head about what's going on here.

Comment: Try running `sudo ldconfig`  (rebuild the library cache; ie. use `ldconfig -p` to print the cache of known libs available for use and you'll likely note what you've done isn't there; rebuild the cache & you might have more luck)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: If you have installed FreeFilesync in /usr/share/applications/FreeFilesync, please verify that your FreeFilesync.desktop file includes the line "Path=/usr/share/applications/FreeFilesync" or if you have installed it in /opt/FreeFilesync, please verify that your .desktop file includes the line "Path=/opt/FreeFilesync". This should solve your problem when starting FreeFilesync in a terminal from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [this forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=313824).
This is an application bug.

> It works fine if I symlink directly to
> .../FreeFileSync/Bin/FreeFileSync_x86_64

```
sudo ln -s /opt/FreeFileSync/Bin/FreeFileSync_x86_64 /usr/bin/FreeFileSync
```

Workarounds:
[How-To install freefilesync on Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045412/how-to-install-freefilesync-on-kubuntu-18-04/1149469#1149469)