# Icons put in /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/apps

Tags: 20.04, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons, mime-type

I want to create a new desktop entry and a new MIME type for an app called FreeFileSync for all users.

I read that it recommends to do in directory `/usr/local/share`. More precisely, the app recommends to locate in `/usr/local/bin` therefore icons, mime types, etc in `/usr/local/share`. It's my mind.

I create a directory structure `/usr/local/share` and put into files:

```
./
├── applications
│   └── FreeFileSync.desktop
├── icons
│   └── hicolor
│       └── apps
│           └── FreeFileSync.png
└── mime
    └── packages
        └── freefilesync-mime.xml
```

I create link `FreeFileSync` in `/usr/loca/bin` to `/opt/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync`

FreeFileSync.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=FreeFileSync
GenericName=Folder Comparison and Synchronization
GenericName[de_DE]=Ordnervergleich und Synchronisation
Exec=FreeFileSync %F
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/apps/FreeFileSync.png
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;FileTools;
MimeType=application/x-freefilesync-ffs;application/x-freefilesync-batch
StartupNotify=true
```

freefilesync-mime.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/x-freefilesync-ffs">
    <comment>new mime type</comment>
    <icon name="FreeFileSync"/>
    <glob pattern="*.ffs_gui"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I execute:

```
update-mime-database -V /usr/local/share/mime
update-desktop-database -v /usr/local/share/applications
```

And yes it's working. But not all.

The icon is not working for `*.ffs_gui`. When I relocate Icon to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/apps` then all is fine (IMPORTANT!!! without `local`).

And desktop entry is fine 'cause it has a full path for the icon.

It seems what Ubuntu don't see that icon direcrories in `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/apps`.

Why can't I use `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/apps` for app I put in `/usr/loca/bin`?

**UPDATE**:

I face the problem, now when I execute FreeFileSync it says:

```
Cannot determine real path for "FreeFileSync".
Error code 2: No such file or directory [realpath]
```

Very strange, there was no problem before.
Solve is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260582/902490), it's FreeFileSync issue.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? I see that at least GNOME and MATE both support the `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/` path normally (I have tested it by `sudo pip3 install retext` on fresh VM - it places all the stuff to `/usr/local`). Please also make sure that you do not have typos in the paths.

Comment: @N0rbert Now I use GNOME then I plan to go to XUBUNTU DESKTOP. What are typos? On what path? In XML have no path? Can I see any logs to check it?

Comment: The problem with your symbolic link might be handled by replacing it with a short wrapper script, that (if needed) can change to the current directory where the main executable is installed before launching it.

Comment: @vanadium Can you give me more information about what you mean?

Comment: Instead of the launcher, a short bash script with the same name, that may contain a `cd` command (if that would be needed) and then the command to start the program.

Comment: @vanadium Unfortunately, this does not affect the icon. The icon doesn't show still.

Comment: I was not expecting it would resolve that issue too.